# C# Hex в строку

Tags: c#, winforms, hex, конвертация

Перевожу строку в Hex так:`textBox3.Text = String.Concat(login.Select(x => ((int)x).ToString("x")));`
А как можно обратно её перевести в текст? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит обратно в текст? У вас и так тут текст везде.

Comment: @tym32167 переменная login например равна "76561200551400337", после перевода в Hex получаю -> "3736353631323030353531343030333337" как мне назад конвертировать Hex "3736353631323030353531343030333337" в текст -> "76561200551400337"

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что вы неправильно конвертируете в hex. Вы походу не число конвертируете, а код каждого символа строки.

Comment: А зачем это всё? Для обучения, или какой-то конкретной задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще таких материалов в поиске много: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615373/c-sharp-convert-hex-string-array-to-byte-array), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array). На русском языке наверное тоже, но я не искал.

Вот пример безопасного преобразования строки в обе стороны на базе консольного приложения

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "Hello World!";
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    string[] h = bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")).ToArray();
    string hex = string.Concat(h);
    Console.WriteLine(hex);

    string[] hexBytes = new string[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hexBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        hexBytes[i] = hex.Substring(i * 2, 2);
    }
    byte[] resultBytes = hexBytes.Select(value => Convert.ToByte(value, 16)).ToArray();
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Hello World!
48656c6c6f20576f726c6421
Hello World!
```